# Android - user preferences synching across devices

Tags: android

I'm working on an app and requirement is that all preferences to be shared across user devices (connected to the user's google account).
Is there any service for Android, like iCloud in iOS, which automatically synchronizes all the user data put in one folder on a phone, or kay-value pairs using API? So each time user changes the settings, they become updated on all devices (therefore Backup API does not do the work)
Drive API would partially be fine, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there's an existing solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at any of the following link, it might help you out

http://support.google.com/android/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=168580

http://ericmiles.wordpress.com/2010/09/22/connecting-the-dots-with-android-syncadapter/

Comment: I know how to implement it, I was just trying to avoid it. My question was if there is something provided by google (integrated in Android). So I don't need to use external cloud storage, which is out of question in my case. Seems like a missing feature for me. Would be cool to have auto sync like iCloud (at least for app shared preferences), where you set the preferences and all is handled by the system.